# detect browser refresh/F5/right click reload in angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a requirement where, Users inputs something and submit then angular does a service call which returns if users input is valid/invalid. If valid take user to success page, if service returns invalid/bad input then user needs to be taken to failure page and should never be able to go back(using back button) or user refresh the page, user should still be on same page. Only option provided to the user should be close browser, there by not allowing using to submit one more request(leading to service call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent the user from not running or editing client-side JavaScript code. Since this is a security requirement against the interest of that particular user, the solution must be server-side:

On the server, after getting the wrong answer, mark the user's profile as such. You may need an additional table in your database joining users and questions for that.

Whenever the user loads the question or submits it, first check the user's flag. If it's set, error out immediately.

Note that this behavior is quite hostile to the user. For instance, the user may accidentally touch <kbd>Enter</kbd> too soon, and will be shut out by your system.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try to implement that.